# R Script - Parsing UTC datetime string

Tags: r, datetime

I'd like to compare two datetimes in UTC format using R script. 
Datetime string looks like this: "2020-01-07T09:36:12.9010676+01:00" 
Found there is a difftime function but I do have problems with parsing timestamps to datetime object.

*# timestr1 = "2020-01-07T09:36:12.9010676+01:00"*

time1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(timestr1,  format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS%z"))

after that part of code, time1 is empty. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is R specific, but the time zone doesn't have a colon ":". For example:

```
> format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS%z")
[1] "2020-02-13T20:08:16+0700"
```

So if you get rid of the colon at the end it may work:

```
> timestr1 = "2020-01-07T09:36:12.9010676+0100"
> as.POSIXct(strptime(timestr1, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS%z"))
[1] "2020-01-07 15:36:12 +07"
```

Comment: Thats the issue. Havn't read entire ISO 8601 but looks its R specific. Thank You.